# Validate uploaded file as image and then get the dimensions of it

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, height, width

I want to upload an image file to FTP server, so I have an `AsyncFileUpload` control on asp.net page. I am using following code to get the type of `AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile` and then trying to get the dimensions of it but having no luck so far.

```
string cType =asyncFU.PostedFile.ContentType;
if (cType.Contains("image"))
{
   Stream ipStream = asyncFU.PostedFile.InputStream;
   Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ipStream); //ERROR comes here, I can't think the work around this.
   int w = img.PhysicalDimension.Width;
   int h = img.PhysicalDimension.Height;
}
```

As you can see, errors message says that it cannot convert from `System.Drawing.Image` to `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image`. i understand the error, but I cannot think the work around this.

I have an `AsyncFileUpload` control where unknown file will be uploaded, but ONLY saved to FTP server if it is an image file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Stream ipStream = fuAttachment.PostedFile.InputStream;
        using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ipStream))
        {                    
            float w = image.PhysicalDimension.Width;
            float h = image.PhysicalDimension.Height;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `img` variable should be of the type `System.Drawing.Image`, not `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image`.